# Excel Clean Up Code VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have some code that works well but I know it can be written much cleaner than what I have.

```
Sub DeleteField()
Range("A6").Select

        Do
            If ActiveCell.Value = "Actual Conveyable Cases" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Projected Non Con" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Actual Non Con Cases" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Projected CPT" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Actual CPT" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Projected Store Loads" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Actual Store Loads" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Projected Pull Ahead" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Actual Pull Ahead" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Projected Loads at 08:00" Or _
            ActiveCell.Value = "Actual Loads at 08:00" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveCell.Select
            Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If

    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0).Value = ""

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to clean up the multiple Or statements.  Is there a way that this can be accomplished with an array or perhaps some way to clean up all of teh "ActiveCell" segments

Comment: Hi, just curious, why do you have this line: ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0).Value = ""? It just seems like you'll be checking 5 extra empty cells when you don't need to.

Comment: the OP apparently wants to keep exactly 5 lines in his data table that do not contain any of the checked strings

Comment: I have that there as a Loop stop because there are breaks in the range from begining to end.  The data has Cell 1:10 then an empty cell then the next 10.  The only way I knew to stop the loop was to use the listed Until code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`SELECT CASE` statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141691) to clean that up:

```
Select Case ActiveCell.Value 
    Case "Actual Conveyable Cases", "Projected Non Con", _
         "Actual Non Con Cases", "Projected CPT", "etc..."

            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete
            ActiveCell.Select

    Case Else

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Select
```

Comment: +1, but how about replacing the 3 lines in the first case with `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I must remember to add the Select Case to my bag of tricks.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would program this to clean it up. Hope it helps.

Also, I removed the condition:
ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0).Value = ""

Because it seemed odd to move down 5 extra cells

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteField()
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iFirstRow As Long, i As Long

    ' define the array here so we don't have to create it over
    ' and over again in the function toDelete()
    Dim list(11) As String
    list(0) = "Actual Conveyable Cases"
    list(1) = "Projected Non Con"
    list(2) = "Actual Non Con Cases"
    list(3) = "Projected CPT"
    list(4) = "Actual CPT"
    list(5) = "Projected Store Loads"
    list(6) = "Actual Store Loads"
    list(7) = "Projected Pull Ahead"
    list(8) = "Actual Pull Ahead"
    list(9) = "Projected Loads at 08:00"
    list(10) = "Actual Loads at 08:00"

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    iFirstRow = 6
    iLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop through the cells from bottom to top (because if we
    ' delete the row it's easier to maintain where we are)
    For i = iLastRow To iFirstRow Step -1
        If (toDelete(list, sh.Cells(i, 1))) Then
            sh.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub

Private Function toDelete(ByRef list() As String, ByRef r As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(list)
        If (r.Value = list(i)) Then
            toDelete = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    toDelete = False
End Function
```

Comment: by the way, I find it funny that I try putting "Hi, " at the beginning of my answer, but it keeps getting removed.

Comment: Because this is a site for programming questions, not IM :)

Comment: @ZevSpitz, touche :) I was just trying to be personable.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the question, the match against multiple values can be done using

```
Dim value As String
Dim matched As Boolean
Dim criteria As String

'** Put all possible strings separated by comma here
criteria = "Actual Conveyable Cases, Projected Non Con, Actual Non Con Cases"

do
   matched = (InStr(1, criteria, ActiveCell.Value) <> 0)

   If matched then

   End If
...
```

The `InStr` function will work because your criteria strings are such that none of the string is contained in another.

i.e. the above will not work if

```
criteria = "Actual Conveyable Cases, Actual Conveyable Cases 1, Actual Conveyable Cases 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have good answers, but as a salesman for the Dictionary object, I obligated to show how fun it can be to use it here. It also works super fast, so if you have a long list of conditions, this could be the way you want. Enjoy!

```
Sub DeleteField()

Dim dict As Object, i As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dict.Add "Actual Conveyable Cases", 1
dict.Add "Projected Non Con", 1
dict.Add "Actual Non Con Cases", 1
dict.Add "Projected CPT", 1
dict.Add "Actual CPT", 1
dict.Add "Projected Store Loads", 1
dict.Add "Actual Store Loads", 1
dict.Add "Projected Pull Ahead", 1
dict.Add "Actual Pull Ahead", 1
dict.Add "Projected Loads at 08:00", 1
dict.Add "Actual Loads at 08:00", 1

For i = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If dict.exists(range("A" & i).Value) Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Since we are in VBA, there is no need to use late-binding (`CreateObject...`). Add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and declare the variable as `Dictionary` or `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the Dictionary by default is case-sensitive. This can be changed by setting `dict.CompareMode = TextCompare`, or to `1` if you are using late-binding and don't have access to the Scripting Runtime contstants.

Comment: Zev, if you wanted to share this VBA code with another user, it's not user-friendly to make them add references. It's more flexible if you just use Create Object.

Comment: For using the Office object models, where there could be multiple versions of the object model and the name changes from version to version, you might be right. But the Microsoft Scripting Runtime has been available on every version of Windows since Windows XP and Office 2000.